# Composer autoload classmap with key value for class name with non-matching filename

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Due to legacy I have a CMS with its own autoloader. Compsoser joined the party to manage some dependencies to ease payment integrations. However, I found the two autoloaders are conflicting with each other. Then I found I can use `classmap` in composer.json, but this doesn't seem to fix my issue - the requested class is not found.

For example I have a `MySQL` class, that resides in a file called `Database.php`. Using classmap so far I have been unable to properly load the `MySQL` class when I enter the filepath to `Database.php` in it. However, using the `files` container it works. But, if possible I want to prevent to brute force include all legacy classes for each page request.

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to define a key-value mapping for a `classmap`-like behavior. Thereby defining my composer.json something like:

```json
{
   "require" : {
     "vendor/payment-service-provider-package": "version-data"
   },
   "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
       "MySQL" => "./CMS/Classes/Database.php",
       "..." => "./CMS/Classes/....php"
     ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to declare the files that declare the classes, and the **generated** autoloader will create the necessary "key-value" mapping.

E.g. I have on `lib/` a couple of files that declare classes will outside PSR-4:

- `FooBar.php` that declares `\Foo` and `\Bar`.
- `FizzBuzz.php` that declares `\Extra\Fizz` and `\Extra\Buzz`.

Also, within `src/` I have the rest of the classes, following PSR-4 standards.

To include all these classes on autloading, I simply declare:

```json
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "lib/"
    ]
  }
}
```

After running `composer dump-autoload`, composer will scan these directories and on `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` I'll get:

```php
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Bar' => $baseDir . '/lib/FooBar.php',
    'Composer\\InstalledVersions' => $vendorDir . '/composer/InstalledVersions.php',
    'Extra\\Buzz' => $baseDir . '/lib/FizzBuzz.php',
    'Extra\\Fizz' => $baseDir . '/lib/FizzBuzz.php',
    'Foo' => $baseDir . '/lib/FooBar.php',
);
```

... that includes all the necessary information to know which file it needs to read for each "not found" class.

Comment: This does exactly what needs to be done. I also found why it wasn't working before. I'm connected through FTP to the server, but ran composer from my local machine. I saw some glitching behavior while I had the `autoload_classmap.php` open, an entry was made and deleted instantaneous. I figured it had to do with the fact I could see all class-files listed, but Composer wasn't able to see and inspect them. Installed and ran composer on the production server and it works like a charm. Thanks! +1A.